# How can I copy text to the clipboard in an Automator JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, macos, automator

I am writing a simple Automator script in JavaScript (because I’m much more productive in JavaScript). For testing purposes, I simply `eval()` the input.

The script is:

```js
//  Workflow receives current text in any application

function run(input, parameters) {
    //  1+2*3
    
    var app = Application.currentApplication()
    app.includeStandardAdditions = true
    
//  app.displayDialog(input)
//  app.displayDialog(input[0])

    result = eval(input[0]) || 0;
    
    app.displayDialog(result)
    app.setTheClipboardTo(result)
    
    return result
}

//  Copy to Clipboard
```

I would like to get the result onto the clipboard. As you see above, I have applied the `setTheClipboardTo()` function.

The Workflow receives the current text.

I have also added the **Copy to Clipboard** action to the end.

I have tried with or without the `setTheClipboardTo()` function, and with or without the **Copy to Clipboard** action. The displayed message has the correct result, but I can’t get it to the clipboard.

Comment: have you been looking to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)?

Comment: @woodz That’s a very dated question about accessing the clipboard on a web browser. Automator is not a browser, and has a completely different API.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know what I did wrong before, except possibly adding the action at the end. Here is a version that works:

```js
//  Workflow receives current text in any application
//  Replaces Selection

function run(input, parameters) {
    //  1*2*3*4*5*6+7-8-9
    //  1 2 3
    
    var app = Application.currentApplication();
    app.includeStandardAdditions = true;
    
    //  Filter for eval()
        expression = input[0].replace(/[^0-9 +\-*\/÷×()]/g,'?')

    try {
        result = eval(input[0])*1;
    } catch(e) {
        result = 0
    }
    
    app.setTheClipboardTo(result.toString())
    
    return result
}
```